# Webアプリケーションのブラウザ表示とC#WindowsフォームのWebBrowserでの表示の判別

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

現在下記2つのアプリケーションを作成しています。
1.Webアプリケーション
2.Windowsフォームアプリケーション

2のフォームアプリケーションは1のWebアプリケーションをForm上で表示するためのアプリです(.netのWebBrowserで1を表示しています)。

1のWebアプリケーションは2のフォームでの表示と、通常のブラウザ(IEやChrome)での表示も行います。

そこで、一部機能を2のフォームアプリケーションからのみ制御可能にしたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

例）リンククリック時に2のアプリ上からだと遷移するが、
IEやChromeからクリックした場合遷移せずにアラートを表示する等

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: どの程度の厳密さを求めているのでしょうか？ 例えばUser-Agentで切り分ける方法が思い浮かびますが。

Comment: ブラウザとフォームアプリからの表示で完全に分けたいと考えています。
区別したいリンク先というのが、フォームアプリケーションが存在するPC上のローカルアプリケーション(○○○.exeなど)を起動するような仕様となっている為、ブラウザからはリンクをクリックしても「このサイトにアクセスできません」というようにエラーなるため、事前にアラートを出し、遷移しないようにしたい、というのが目的です。

User-Agentで完全に切り分けることは可能でしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あらゆる通信は模倣することが可能なため、ブラウザーを判別し「完全に切り分け」ることは不可能です。何らかの妥協が必要です。

---

エラー抑止程度が目的で厳密性を求める理由がよくわかりませんでした。
WebBrowserコントロールのUser-Agentに独自のキーワードを組み込んでおき、Webサーバー側は独自のキーワードがあればリンクを開き、なければ警告する、他のブラウザーがUser-Agentを模倣した場合は誤判定するがその点は気にしない、程度の実装が浮かびました。もちろん誤判定があるため完全ではありません。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
ブラウザからリンククリック時にリンクが存在しない旨のアラートを表示してエラー画面に遷移しないという部分のみでしたら方法はありますでしょうか？
XMLHttpRequestでstatus確認は試してみたのですが、この場合正常に200が返ってきてしまうため判別には使用できませんでした。

Comment: 確かにエラー抑止にそこまで厳密性は必要ありませんでした。
WebBrowserコントロールのUser-Agentにキーワード追加で実現できました。ありがとうございます。